# Entity Framework Core: Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, migration

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una solución que contiene dos proyectos: API_Paises (WebAPI) y DAL (librería de clases), en este ultima tengo lo relacionado los paquetes de EF: EF.SQLServer y EF.Tools:

[image: Estructura proyecto]

Tengo configurado el DbContext de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Ciudad> Ciudades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Departamento> Departamentos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pais> Paises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Barrio> Barrios { get; set; }

}
```

Y en la clase program de la WebAPI tengo lo siguiente:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB")));
```

Estoy tratando de hacer la primera migración de la siguiente forma: Establezco como proyecto de inicio el DAL y en la consola de paquetes tambien lo selecciono como proyecto predeterminado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al ejecutar el comando Add-Migration tengo el siguiente error:

Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría dos cosas:

1. Que la línea
   `builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB")));`
   del program.cs esté antes de `var app = builder.Build()`
2. Si con eso no se arregla, prueba a darle más log al añadir la migración: `Add-Migration "NuevaEntidadBarrios" -verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciono justo como dijo Jose C.

gracias

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AplicationDbContext>(options =>                    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowWebApp",
builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()));
var app = builder.Build();
```